# when delete data from big table led the db can't access

Tags: oracle, delete

when use delete from statement to delete data month by month to clean old data,found it runs slower and slower,and couples of hours later,the DB can not access，and with such error msg as pic shows.

the target_table has 60 million data(104 months) ,below will delete 28 million data (75 months).

and below sql run about 7 hours and Now I can not access DB, and the DB is Oracle 12c release 1

```
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20130630','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20130731','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20130831','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20130930','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20131031','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20131130','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20131231','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140131','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140228','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140331','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140430','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140531','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140630','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140731','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140831','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20140930','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20141031','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20141130','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20141231','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150131','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150228','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150331','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --127974
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150430','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --328466
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150531','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --328560
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150630','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --328658
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150731','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --330236
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150831','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --331048
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20150930','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --331806
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20151031','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341706
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20151130','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341772
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20151231','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341850
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160131','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341874
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160229','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341886
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160331','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341906
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160430','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341922
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160531','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341954
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160630','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341960
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160731','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --341972
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160831','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342004
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20160930','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342006
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20161031','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342028
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20161130','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342070
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20161231','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342202
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170131','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342228
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170228','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342252
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170331','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342264
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170430','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342328
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170531','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342342
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170630','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342346
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170731','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342392
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170831','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342462
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20170930','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342478
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20171031','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342508
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20171130','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342528
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20171231','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342530
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180131','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342550
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180228','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342580
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180331','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342656
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180430','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342658
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180531','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342670
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180630','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342778
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180731','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342778
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180831','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342778
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20180930','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342778
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20181031','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342782
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20181130','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --342816
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20181231','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1157756
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190131','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1159653
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190228','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1161527
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190331','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1163206
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190430','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1164827
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190531','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1166118
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190630','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1167498
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190731','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1168844
delete from target_table where cycle_mth = to_date('20190831','yyyymmdd'); 
 commit;      --1170300
```

[image: sql developer errer msg]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question, include the `DELETE` statement you're executing, and tell us the number of rows you're deleting from whatever tables are involved. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob updated ,please refer

Comment: Why in the world are you performing a commit after every statement??

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes，is that not correct？

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes,I commit after each statement

Comment: @OldProgrammer Some colleague tell me need commit，do not delete too much data in one statement

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022

Comment: Commit after every delete probably to avoid running out of UNDO space. Find out which index is being used, then ANALYZE the index after every few deletes. See if that makes a difference. But a better way would be, given how the delete is keyed on a date column, to consider partitioning the table by date ranges, then your delete process simply becomes a drop partition.

Comment: @TenG The DBA reply the cause of the can't connection to DB，Does the archive log is giant is relative to my delete and commit statement？

Comment: I think you're really better off changing the system that generates the delete statements so that it produces date ranges, then use a series of deletes with `between` statements

Comment: As already mentioned, the error has nothing to do with archive logs, but with undo storage being filled. Your undo must be large enough to accomodate the largest transaction, i.e. the one that deletes the largest number of rows. Is this what the numbers in comments represents ? Now: you did not say what version you use, but I assume it is very old and no longer supported since the error message still talks about “rollback segments” and the terminology was changed to “undo segments” ages ago.

Comment: As for each delete taking longer and longer, that is probably because each deletes more and more data: this is most likely some sort of transaction data and any business is expected to grow and generate more and more of those. An interesting action would be to count how many rows are in each batch: a simple COUNT() with GROUP BY will do that. Then see which batch failed, what is the largest one and increase the size of the undo (rollback to you) table space accordingly.

Comment: This takes a long time ? Well yes. It does quite a lot of work: finding rows to delete (is there an index on the  cycle_mth column?), removing each from all the indexes (are there many ?), writing the undo, writing the redo (maybe do the process without redo ?). Then again you are removing close to 1/2 of the table ... and you don’t say what hardware you use and on what resource the process is maxing out (CPU ? I/O ?) and even what sort of hardware ? Given that this is a one-off, my approach would be to create a new table copy only retaining those rows you want to retain.

Comment: @Albert, the Oracle is 12C r1,BTW,why the DBA said the giant archive logs due to huge transactions

Comment: Ah ok. Strange that the error messages still refer to « rollback segments ». Obviously the more updates you do, the more content will be stored in the archive logs (and that included undo info). The create-table-as-select won’t have that issue. Did you try it ?

Comment: please do not post pictures of text but post a well formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting in batches.
Pros: 
 Will be able to commit after each 500/1000 row deletion , so less undo segment will be sufficient.
Cons:
 The batching will increase the total time that this process is going to take.

For batching you can develop pl/sql api . The input to that api can be your table_name and and cycle_mth.

Psudo code :

```
    create or replace procedure archive_api(in_table_name varcahr2,in_date) 
    is
    cursor curr_data is 
    select rowid from in_table_name  where cycle_mth = to_date(in_date,'yyyymmdd'); 
    t_rowids  is table of varchar2(400);
    l_rowids t_rowids := t_rowids();
    l_limit :=1000;
    begin
    open curr_data 
    loop 

    fetch curr_data bulk collect into l_rowids limit l_limit;
    exit when l_rowids.count = 0;
      FORALL i IN l_rowids.first .. l_rowids.last
        DELETE from in_table_name   where rowid= l_rowids(i);
    commit;
    end loop;
    end
    /
```

Please refere:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i

Answer (score 0):

Given that this throws away almost 1/2 the content of the table, I recommend creating a new table with only the rows you retain. That will be very fast. But of course you then nead to also recreate all the indexes. But all together this will be MUCH faster than this series of individual deletions (and not subject to UNDO issues).

Added benefits are that you will have a nice clean and compact new table with optimal storage and indexes.

The syntax will be:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * FROM old_table
WHERE cycle_mth not in ( ..., ..., ...);
```

or simpler

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * FROM old_table
WHERE cycle_mth > your max cycle;
```

Then create all indexes (with new names) and eventually drop the old table and rename the new one.

A longer term solution would be to partition the table by cycle month which will make this sort of maintenance trivial (assuming you are running EE and own the partitioning option).

NOTES: I updated the SELECT statements to correctly specify the rows to RETAIN (my original syntax was wrong). It should be:

```
WHERE cycle_mth not in ( ..., ..., ...);
```

or:

```
WHERE cycle_mth > your max cycle;
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle this would be to recreate `TARGET_TABLE` as a partitioned table, interval-partitioned on `CYCLE_MTH`. That way the database will create partitions as they're needed, and instead of deleting row-by-row you just drop the partitions that you don't want any more when you're done with them. If you define all your indexes as being `LOCAL` the partition drops will execute almost instantly, all indexes will remain valid, and your life will get a lot simpler.

Don't ask me how I know. :-)

Best of luck.

Comment: you should remember I have asked you some queries about the partition table, The delete problem is a preparation for that...